# Jquery not getting dynamic dropdown value

Tags: php, jquery

> In this code when I am selecting from 1st dropdown its getting the
>   value but in next its not getting the value from jquery ..

```
<?php
$con=mysql_connect('localhost','root','root');
mysql_select_db('alok',$con);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post">
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Item</td>
        <td>status</td>
        <td>dropdown</td>
    </tr>
    <?php 
    $query="select * from jain";
    $result=mysql_query($query);
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
      ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['gift']; ?>
        </td>
        <td><?php if($row['status']==='0'){echo 'pending';}elseif($row['status']==='1'){echo 'Recieved';}else{
            echo 'Rejected';} ?></td>

        <td>

            <select name="status" id="status">
                <option value="0">Pending</option>
                <option value="1">Recieved</option>
                <option value="2">Rejected</option>
            </select>
        </td>

    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#status').change(function(){
        var status=$('#status option:selected').val();
        alert(status);
    })
    })

</script>
```

when selecting from first dropdown:
[image]

when selecting from second dropdown not getting alert:
[image]

what I am doing wrong here please let me know i am a newbie here

Comment: `ID should be unique` also dynamically added element should use event delegation use `.on()`

Comment: can u please update my question >??

Answer (score 0):

Use different `id` for select. Then you will get the other selected value.

```
<select name="status" id="status1">
    <option value="0">Pending</option>
    <option value="1">Recieved</option>
    <option value="2">Rejected</option>
</select>
<select name="status" id="status2">
    <option value="0">Pending</option>
    <option value="1">Recieved</option>
    <option value="2">Rejected</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating  your  select elements in a php loop. Hence Id's are same for all. They should be unique.

You should consider change id to class and it works.

```
<select name="status" id="status" class="status">
```

and

```
$('.status').change(function(){
        var status=$("option:selected", this).val();
        alert(status);
    })
```

Comment: its working but how this sected value get to know that which id i am going to update